# Connect via ip address to device through VPN doesn't work

Tags: ios, network, wifi, xcode, vpn

I'm trying to connect to my device that's connected through VPN. I am able to connect to it on the same network but as soon as I am on a different network but connect to the same network through VPN I cannot connect to the device through VPN.

I can ping my device by ip address but when I try the option "Connect via IP Address" in "Devices & Simulators > Right click device" it says that my device is not found. Is there a way to solve this or is it just not possible to connect through VPN?

> Device containing XCode (which it has to connect to)   **iMac 2019 MacOS**
> **Monterey 12.4**
>
> Internal ip:
> **10.0.0.174**
>
> Device that wants to connect through VPN
> **iPhone X iOS 15.5 Internal**
>
> ip: **10.212.134.200**

Comment: "connect" how?  Via what protocol?

Comment: Connect through XCode. Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Click device -> Connect via network. 

Disconnect device and right click on device then "Connect via IP Address". Not sure what protocol XCode exactly uses for this.

Comment: Can you connect to other devices in the VPN network? Do the two local networks - the one you're connecting from and the one you're connecting to via VPN - use different IP address ranges? It won't work if they use the same IP range.

Comment: They use the same ip range and they can ping each other

Comment: Is it possible that you’re  using the private address of your device (the one you see as a member of the local network) and you simply do not use the public address? If the IP you use from outside is something like 192.168.x.x - that’s a private address. won’t work.

Comment: I like to suggest that the OP provides more details on the setup he is using. Which devices, which are running which OS version, which programs or apps are involved and which version of these, which IP adresses - at least the first two parts of the network id, for private and public networks? And what exactly what they want to acchieve?

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? You need to be on the same network in order for it to work. The iMac which has XCode on it is on the main network. The iPhone is on a different network. For that reason I connect to a VPN with the iPhone which allows it to be on the same network as the iMac. At this point they are both seen as on the same local network and they can ping each other. However XCode still can't find my iPhone. I have just added some more details of the devices.

Comment: @slartibartfast If OP is on said "local network" by using VPN then OP don't need to use public IP address to connect to the device, since practically their device is on the same network (and that's why they can ping each other with private/internal IP address). At least on Windows, it'd work with private/internal IP address, so I suppose MacOS/iOS/iPadOS should work.

Comment: Just noticed the local ip addresses are different subnets. Could that be the reason? They can however ping each other

Comment: @SinanSamet That could be the reason. I don't know how Xcode device searching works, but almost all of software that I've used to remote control devices only searches devices that are on same subnet. Is it possible to reallocate your iPhone's IP address to 10.0.0.x?